# Jquery replace in html string 2 times separatly

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So i have a html template:

```
      <div style='background-color: red;'>
          <div>
                $QuestionUpButton
              <%--<img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="onAddQUestionVote" src="../../Images/arrow-up-24-ns.png" data-questionvoteupbutton="$i" id='addQuestionVote' alt='Vote up' data-questionid='$questionUid' />--%>
              <span data-questionvotegroup='$i'>$QuestionVote</span>
              <span data-questiontextgroup='$i'>$textboxText<br />
              </span>
          </div>
          <div id="mm" style='background-color: white;'>
              $AnswerUpVote
              <%--<img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="onAddAnswerVote" src="../../Images/arrow-up-24-ns.png" data-answervoteupbutton="$i" id='addAnswerVote' alt='Vote up' data-answeruid='$answerGuid' />--%>
              <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="onRemoveAnswerVote" src="../../Images/arrow-down-24-ns.png" data-answervotedownbutton="$i" id='removeAnswerVote' alt='Vote down' data-answeruid='$answerGuid' />
              <span data-answervotegroup='$i'>$AnswerVotes</span>
              <span data-labelgroup='$i'>Answer : </span>
              <span data-answertextgroup="$i" data-questionid='$questionUid' data-answerid="$answerGuid">$AnswerSpan</span>
              <input type='button' id='editButton' data-editlinkbuttongroup="$i" value='Edit' />
              <input type='button' id='deleteButton' data-deletelinkbuttongroup="$i" value='Delete Question' />
          </div>

      </div>
```

on document load i run code where i replace all $ variables like this:

```
function MyFunction(result) {
    //console.log(result);
    var panel = $('#mypanel');
    var userGuid = GetUserGuid().d;
    var panel = $('#MainContent_AnsweredQuestions_mypanel');

    for (var k = 0; k < result.d.length; k++) {
        var notVotedQuestion = "<img style='cursor: pointer' onclick='onAddQUestionVote' src='../../Images/arrow-up-24-ns.png' data-questionvoteupbutton='" + i + "' id='Img1' alt='Vote up' data-questionid='" + result.d[k].Uid + "' />";
        var notVotedQuestion1 = "hulabula";
        var notVotedAnswer = "notVotedAnswer";
        var votedAnswer = "";

        console.log(result.d[k].Uid)
        var html = $("#OwnerTemplateQuestionWithoutAnswer").html().replace(/\$i/g, i)
            .replace(/\$AnswerSpan/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].Conetent)
            .replace(/\$answerGuid/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].Uid)
            .replace(/\$questionUid/g, result.d[k].Uid)
            .replace(/\$QuestionVote/g, result.d[k].QuestionVotes.length)
            .replace(/\$AnswerVotes/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].AnswerVotes.length)
            .replace(/\$textboxText/g, result.d[k].Content);

        //var html1 = $("#OwnerTemplateQuestionWithoutAnswer").html(html);

        if (didUserVote(result.d[k], userGuid) == false){
            html.html().replace("$AnswerUpVote", notVotedQuestion); 
        }

        panel.append(html);
        i++;


    }

}
```

part where i replace first time is working great and exactly how i want:

```
 var html = $("#OwnerTemplateQuestionWithoutAnswer").html().replace(/\$i/g, i)
                .replace(/\$AnswerSpan/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].Conetent)
                .replace(/\$answerGuid/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].Uid)
                .replace(/\$questionUid/g, result.d[k].Uid)
                .replace(/\$QuestionVote/g, result.d[k].QuestionVotes.length)
                .replace(/\$AnswerVotes/g, result.d[k].Answers[0].AnswerVotes.length)
                .replace(/\$textboxText/g, result.d[k].Content);
```

but later in the code i need to load image differently depends on some conditions

```
   if (didUserVote(result.d[k], userGuid) == false){
        html.html().replace("$AnswerUpVote", notVotedQuestion); 
    }
```

and this part of cide doesnt work at all... Any suggestions on how to solve this, or how i can improve replacement in some kind of a way??

Comment: You might want to look into a JavaScript templating framework, e.g. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/ http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template or http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: i looked alot into JQuery.template, but it is no longer supported, + all of them have poorly suport for loading with conditions. Or at least i couldnt find any real example where they show loading with conditions from outside of template.

Comment: Take a look at this page of mustache examples: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html . It contains examples of how to apply conditional logic and loops to your templates.

Comment: looks like i found my template solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
html.html().replace("$AnswerUpVote", notVotedQuestion);
```

To this:

```
var html = $("#OwnerTemplateQuestionWithoutAnswer");
html.html(html.html().replace("$AnswerUpVote", notVotedQuestion));
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because in the first instance you are assigning the new Html to the var html; later, since the object is already created, you need to set its Html value to the updated (replaced/filtered) html code of itself. when you call .html() you are getting a string that is passed by value, not by reference, which is why when you were just replace the .html(), you were replacing it but you weren't doing anything with the result.

Comment: its failing with : TypeError: html.html is not a function (its first html.html which fails) i think variables doesnt have html, as a function or?

Comment: I see your 'html' var was local to the other function. Try the updated code in my answer.

Comment: it wouldnt work, since new var html gonna be a local if loop variable

Comment: What does that even mean? It sounds like you need to post more of your code if it affects stuff we can't see.

Comment: if i run your suggestion, it doesnt load templates which run into the if statement (meant if statement, not loop sry)

Comment: Then it sounds like your logic is wrong. If you need it to run every time, then why do you have the If statement?

Comment: its just condtiional replacing on the fly

Answer (score 0):

well I am not sure you concluded a solution for above but I would strongly recomend you to use mustache js.

Mustache is a “logic-less” template syntax. “Logic-less” means that it doesn’t rely on procedural statements (if, else, for, etc.): Mustache templates are entirely defined with tags.

So you do not need above hard to understand javascript logic to do what you want to achive.

Check [Mustache.JS](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://mustache.github.com/&ei=wKd-UKKIGpHKrAftj4EI&usg=AFQjCNGB5SwnAZJriMnK2DjI2Y0o4VTeDA)  and it's [template](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/) tutorials.